# How to make nested object oriented function calls in GO

Tags: oop, go

I'm trying to make my Go application more object oriented. Right now I have the following call:

```
groups.AllGroups = GrowGroupsArray(groups.AllGroups)
```

Which calls:

```
func GrowGroupsArray(g []Group) []Group {
    newSlice := make([]Group, len(g), 2*cap(g)+1)
    copy(newSlice, g)
    g = newSlice
    return g
}
```

This technically works but I would rather this:

```
//groups is of type Groups
//AllGroups is of type []Group
groups.AllGroups.GrowGroupsArray()

func (g Groups) GrowGroupsArray() {
    newSlice := make([]Group, len(g), 2*cap(g)+1)
    copy(newSlice, g)
    g.AllGroups = newSlice
}
```

This compiles fine but I get a runtime panic because nothing is being saved to the object when the function is completed (out of scope). I've encountered the exact same issue in several places where the first example works but the second will not save the new array to my object. The old array persists after the function has been called. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use a pointer method and you're good.

Comment: Yeah that totally worked. Thanks!

Comment: BTW you do know that you are emulating what `append` does implicitly, right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just needed to do this:

```
//groups is of type Groups
//AllGroups is of type []Group
groups.AllGroups.GrowGroupsArray()

func (g *Groups) GrowGroupsArray() { //<- Make this a pointer method
    newSlice := make([]Group, len(g), 2*cap(g)+1)
    copy(newSlice, g)
    g.AllGroups = newSlice
}
```

Comment: You do realize that `append` does this already, and more efficiently?

Comment: No I didn't. I'm very new to Go and must have missed it in the docs. Thank you. I'm always trying to make my code better. :)

Comment: Since you've already missed some basics like pointers and slice handling, I would suggest re-running through the docs. Also, regarding your first sentence, no one really strives to make their Go application "more object oriented" (whatever that might mean). You can bundle data and behavior with methods, and use interfaces for polymorphism, but there's no OO requirement to fulfill in Go.